# uploading to YouTube with ASP.NET C# - avoiding the "Google login" screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, upload, youtube-api

I am creating an ASP.NET C# app that uploads videos to a YouTube Channel.
*I have already read through (to the best of my ability) the documentation at

[The YouTube API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference)

I have been able to successfully implement two examples of uploading a video to the YouTube channel using the sample code provided.

For example, using direct method (only the important code attached):

```
<!-- eja: import the google libraries -->
 <%@ Import Namespace="Google.GData.Client" %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="Google.GData.Extensions" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Google.GData.YouTube" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>

<!-- some more code -->
 <%
    // specify where to go to once authenticated
    Uri targetUri = new Uri(Request.Url, "VideoManager.aspx");

    // hide the link to authenticate for now.
    GotoAuthSubLink.Visible = false;
    // GotoAuthSubLink.Visible = true;

    // look for a session var storing the auth token. if it's not empty
    if (Session["token"] != null)
    {
        // go to the VideoManager link
        Response.Redirect(targetUri.ToString());
    }
    else if (Request.QueryString["token"] != null)
    {
        // if we have the auth key in the URL, grab it from there instead
        String token = Request.QueryString["token"];
        // set the session equal to AuthSubUtil's calling the exchangeForSessionToken method
        // returns the token and convert it to a string 
        Session["token"] = AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken(token, null).ToString();
        Response.Redirect(targetUri.ToString(), true);
    }
    else 
    {
        //no auth token, display the link and create the token by loading the google
        // auth page

        String authLink = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(Request.Url.ToString(), "http://gdata.youtube.com", false, true);
        GotoAuthSubLink.Text = "Login to your Google Account";
        GotoAuthSubLink.Visible = true;
        GotoAuthSubLink.NavigateUrl = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(Request.Url.ToString(),"http://gdata.youtube.com",false,true);

    }

 <asp:HyperLink ID="GotoAuthSubLink" runat="server"/>
```

That's page one...it loads the google authentication screen. (see link to attached image ,it's safe, I just set up a new account here on stackOverflow and can't upload images yet).

[image: Twitpic image of google authentication screen]

Then it leads to a page with the upload mechanism...The uploading works I am not worried about that, but here is the snippet of code FYI.

```
       // create an instance ot the YouTubeService class. passing the application name and my DEV KEY
        YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(authFactory.ApplicationName, **API_KEY**);

        // retrieve the current session token as a string if any
        authFactory.Token = HttpContext.Current.Session["token"] as string;
        // incorporate the information into our service
        service.RequestFactory = authFactory;

        try
        {
            // a YouTubeEntry object is single entity within a videoFeed object. It generally contains info
            // about the video. when uploading, we will assign the values that we received to the feed.

            YouTubeEntry entry = new YouTubeEntry();

            // aggregate all the initial descriptor information
            entry.Media = new Google.GData.YouTube.MediaGroup();
            entry.Media.Description = new MediaDescription(this.Description.Text);
            entry.Media.Title = new MediaTitle(this.Title.Text);
            entry.Media.Keywords = new MediaKeywords(this.Keyword.Text);

            // process  entry.Media.Categories to assign the category
            MediaCategory category = new MediaCategory(this.Category.SelectedValue);
            category.Attributes["scheme"] = YouTubeService.DefaultCategory;
            entry.Media.Categories.Add(category);

            // prepare the token used for uploading
            FormUploadToken token = service.FormUpload(entry);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["form_upload_url"] = token.Url;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["form_upload_token"] = token.Token;

            // construct the URL
            string page = "http://" + Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];

            if (Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
            {
                page += ":" + Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
            }
            page += Request.ServerVariables["URL"];

            HttpContext.Current.Session["form_upload_redirect"] = page;
            Response.Redirect("UploadVideo.aspx");
```

The page UploadVideo.aspx is the actual upload form, and it works, so I am not concerned about that.

The alternate method is not the recommended method, as it's synchronous in nature, but it DOES avoid that login screen as it allows us to pass credentials to authenticate (it works as a web app)...again principal code attached below.

```
<%
    GAuthSubRequestFactory authFactory = new GAuthSubRequestFactory(ServiceNames.YouTube, "TesterApp");
     // Response.Write("serviceNames.youtube=" + ServiceNames.YouTube + "<br />");
    YouTubeRequestSettings s = new YouTubeRequestSettings(authFactory.ApplicationName, **your API KEY**,**Your email account as a username**,**your password**);

YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(s);
Video newVideo = new Video();
newVideo.Title = "test at 4:40";
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Games", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny";
newVideo.Description = "My description";
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
// newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

// newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);
// alternatively, you could just specify a descriptive string
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Somewhere,Someplace");

newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("C:\\IMG_1672.MOV",
  "video/quicktime");
Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
Response.Write("This will print out once the file is uploaded...indicates that the code is <i>synchronous</i>. The cursor spins around until done. go get a coffee then check the YouTube Channel");

 %>
```

So basically the question that I am asking is - Is there a method that will upload a video to a YouTube Channel in ASP.NET C# code a) for a web application b) that I can pass credentials through the code to  c) bypass the Google authentication screen seen above and d) without using OAuth and openID and a cert etc?

The App is for only a short campaign (November only) and I am happy to use the deprecated authSubUtil and a dev key and do not need to worry about oAuth 2.x or open ID (since authsubutil will deprecate in 2015 anyway).

Any Help is appreciated.

thanks

Edward

Comment: Mr. Apostol - I edited your doc to display the image. If this was the wrong image, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best placed to use the ClientLogin authentication, where you can store a users username & password for their account and then use DirectUpload.

Direct Upload: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Direct_Upload

ClientLogin: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin#ClientLogin_Authentication

Note client login is being deprecated, and they want you to use OAuth, however if you do it quickly you should be okay!